# NServiceBus - Nested Full Duplex Scenario

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I am new to NServiceBus and have been playing around with NServiceBus samples for not more than two days. I have had a look at the Full Duplex messaging sample and it works fine for me.

But now, I am trying to implement a nested full duplex scenario where

- my client endpoint "A" would send a message to server endpoint "B" and wait for reply from "B"
- my server endpoint "B" would send a message to server endpoint "C" and wait for reply from "C"
- server endpoint "C" would reply to server endpoint "B" then
- server endpoint "B" would reply to client endpoint "A"

I have made a copy of the server endpoint from sample code (off course changed project name and namespaces etc.) to have two server endpoints, but the message from client "A" gets as far as server "B" which fails to publish it to server "C". All I get is a couple of retries and later a failure.

> WARN  NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager [(null)] <(null)> -
>   Message has failed FLR and will be handed over to SLR for retry
>   attempt: 4, MessageID=c07c5e38-f355-4f01-a67d-a30a011545a1.
>
> ERROR NServiceBus.SecondLevelRetries.SecondLevelRetriesProcessor
>   [(null)] <(null)> - SLR has failed to resolve the issue with message
>   c07c5e38-f355-4f01-a67d-a30a011545a1 and will be forwarded to the
>   error queue

My question is if this is an invalid NServiceBus scenario that I am trying? If not, what could I be missing here?

Comment: You should have more information in the log regarding the failure. have a look at the log entries prior to SLR failure. also the message in the error queue should have some metadata bout the exception

Comment: Agree with @Simon - but without addressing exact problem, this is a possible scenario with NServiceBus, but trying to force asynchronous messaging to look like RPC (much less nested RPC) is not really something that you would/should commonly be doing. More code would be helpful to see how you are doing your waits.

Comment: Thanks guys, yea after reading further about it I realized NServiceBus doesn't support RPC style messaging. In our environment, most of the communication is asynchronous but for a few of scenarios we needed RPC style messaging without the need to implement a separate communication pattern than existing service bus - unfortunately for that reason we gave up on NServiceBus.